# Pie chart size is based on calculate value. How to set it fix as design to look good in preview?

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing problem in Design view while generating SSRS report.

I have 9- 10 pie charts placed at random location on white board in Design View. Those pie charts are linked with each other by Line.

On previewing design, All position of lines and Pie Chart gets disturbed and pie chart/Lines position either gets changes or it gets vanished.

Is there any way to lock the design and have preview of pie chart and connecting lines same as we draw in Design view?
In my design I always make sure not to overlap lines with browser of Pie Chart. But still issue exists.

In my case size of pie chart and width of Lines are set dynamically based on count of Database records.

Hope you may know locking the design.

Or Do you know Is there anything in SSRS like chord diagram in Power BI ?

I want to show relationships. In below capture you can see how pie charts are relationships are shown.

For eg: Persons, Documents, Virtual Items etx all are objects here and they are related. This can also be shown in chord diagram instead of pie charts and lines

So any other option to show relationships?
[image]
Thanks,
Priyanka

Comment: Hi, welcome to **stackoverflow**, you should create a *jsfiddle* or *code snippet* for us to help you.

Comment: Add all your chart into one single rectangle control and set rectangle properties (using right click)>General  > Page break option >check "Keep content together"